# Converting Mixpanel cURL request to Node JS POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I am using the node `request` module for my HTTP calls. I can't figure out how to convert the request below to a `request` post request.

```
curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql \
    -u ce08d087255d5ceec741819a57174ce5: \
    --data-urlencode script@query.js | python -m json.tool
```